# Insert the data to table from vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've found the following VBA code to generate the `sCode string.

But how do I insert `sCode` into `Table1`.

I'm new to **MS Access** programming.

```
Private Sub Command120_Click()
 Dim sCode As String
   Dim i As Long
   For i = 1 To Me.Qty
      sCode = Format(Now(), "YYMMDDHHNNSS") & Format(i, "0000")
   Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

At least two ways - in both I'll assume the field itself is called `sCode`...

1) Use DAO:

```
Private Sub Command120_Click()
  Dim RS AS DAO.Recordset, sCode As String, i As Long
  Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1")
  For i = 1 To Me.Qty
    sCode = Format(Now(), "YYMMDDHHNNSS") & Format(i, "0000")
    RS.AddNew
    RS!sCode = sCode
    RS.Update
  Next i
End Sub
```

2) Use an SQL statement:

```
Private Sub Command120_Click()
  Dim DB AS DAO.Database, sCode As String, i As Long
  Set DB = CurrentDb
  For i = 1 To Me.Qty
    sCode = Format(Now(), "YYMMDDHHNNSS") & Format(i, "0000")
    DB.Execute("INSERT INTO Table1 (sCode) VALUES ('" + sCode + "')");
  Next i
End Sub
```

You may also want to wrap things up in a transaction if you want to be sure none rather than some of the updates will go through when there is an error.